# Back ground images animation scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have punch of images(5-6 images) that should animatedly scrolling on back ground with different speed. I put them just on UIView not in UIScrollView.

Right now I have this method for it: 
[image: Method screen]

I adding images on the screen that user see and copy of images behind the screen. But because of that images and copyImages(behind the screen) must pass the same distance them has different speed(Not that I put).
So it's not working properly for me.

Could anyone help with that?

P.S. Some images has different size so i need change yPos for them. Just for elaboration.

```
func setUpBackGroundLayersWithArray(){

    var xPos: CGFloat = 0

    for  (index,image) in self.backGroundsImages.reverse().enumerate(){
        var yPos:CGFloat = -30

        switch index {
        case 1: yPos = -10
                xPos = 320
        case 2: yPos = -10
        default: yPos = -30
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        let copyimageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        copyimageView.frame = CGRectMake(320, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        copyimageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(copyimageView)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:8 - Double(index + 1), curve: .Linear, animations: {
            UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0 - copyimageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: nil)
        })
        let secondAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:10 - Double(index + 1), curve: .Linear, animations: {
            UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
                copyimageView.frame = CGRectMake(0-copyimageView.frame.size.width,  copyimageView.frame.origin.y,  copyimageView.frame.size.width,  copyimageView.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: nil)
        })

        self.animators.append(animator)
        self.animators.append(secondAnimator)
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be easier to put them in a scroll view with a horizontal stack view inside, or a collection view, then just animate the content offset of the scrollview at the speed and repeat count you need?  Also, it's best to copy the code into your question. Makes life easier for answering.

Comment: @twiz_ I tried it but scroll view not work properly and more than that i can't add different scroll speed for different images

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UICollectionView` for simple showing and animating on images. For animation you need use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method after needed time interval

Comment: Hmm... not sure but can't imagine how to repeat images scrolling with collection view...

Comment: Do you want endless scrolling?

Comment: Yes. You know as it showing in games. Infinity background scrolling. But i doing it inside Widget so it has some confines for me.

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView` for your goals. read [this article](https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/) to understand how add endless scrolling

Comment: Thanks I'll try! What do you think about complexity and memory taking of this method? Be cause it will place into Widget, solution shouldn't take a lot of memory.

Comment: So I have check CollectionView way for my goals and thats can't help me, 'cause it very hard to make collection view with punch of images and put different speed scrolling for each image. 
So the question is open.